# Folder structure for GUID named files

Tags: cloud-storage, public-folders, guid

I'm contemplating building an app sort of like a personal wiki, where each page is to be stored in a file named using the GUID identifying the document. Estimating storage from a few hundred to several thousand files on either a cloud storage like Dropbox or Google Drive, or some random Linux server.

*What kind of folder structure would be suitable to have decent read/write access to a somewhat large number of files? Or should I just keep everything in the same folder?*

I'm old enough to remember when dos/windows got serious problems when having more than 128 files in the same folder, but not sure if this is any issue anymore, and I welcome any facts regarding similar limits of the file systems of today.